# Does it converge? $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{2^n}(1+\frac{1}{n})^{n^2}$

Tags: sequences-and-series

Does it converge? $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{2^n}(1+\frac{1}{n})^{n^2}$

I've used two methods and it converged, but when I checked wolfram it says it diverges.

First I've tried $\frac{1}{2^n}(1+\frac{1}{n})^{n^2} \le \frac{1}{2^n}e^2 \le e^2$, Thus converges.

Second I've tried, the $lim_{n=0}^\infty {a_n}^{\frac{1}{n}}$ which got me to $\frac{1}{2}$.

I'd love some opinions..

Comment: I think you are misinterpreting the $n^2$.  The way you have typeset it, this is $(1+1/n)^{(n^2)}$, rather than $((1+1/n)^n)^2)$.

Comment: You seem under the false impression that the identity $a^{n^2}=(a^n)^2$ holds, which could not be further from truth. $a^{n^2}=(a^n)^n$, and $(a^{n})^2=a^{2n}$.

Comment: Also, "$a_n\le e^2$ Thus converges" = "no". It would be true (if it were true) that $(0\le)a_n\le \frac1{2^n}e^2$ implies convergence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

we have $$\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^{n^2}}{2^n}=\infty$$

Comment: Yes because it is $e^n:2^n$

Answer (score 4):

For large values of $n$ we have $(\frac{n+1}{n})^n>2.7$ since $(\frac{n+1}{n})^n$ converges to $e$.

So we have that $(\frac{(n+1)}{n})^{n^2}>2.7^n$ for large values of $n$.

It follows that not only does the series diverge, but also $\frac{1}{2^n}(\frac{(n+1)}{n})^{n^2}$ diverges to infinity. (since it is greater that $(\frac{2.7}{2})^n$ for large values of $n$)
.

Answer (score 4):

Following the root test with $$a_n=\dfrac {1}{2^n}\left(1+\dfrac {1}{n}\right)^{n^2} $$
We have that $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\left\vert(a_n)^{\frac {1}{n}}\right\vert=\lim_{n\to\infty}\dfrac {1}{2^{(n\cdot\frac{1}{n})}}\cdot\left(1+\dfrac {1}{n}\right)^{n^2\cdot\frac{1}{n}}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\dfrac {1}{2}\left(1+\dfrac {1}{n}\right)^{n}=\dfrac{e}{2}\approx\dfrac{2.72}{2}>1$$
which implies divergence.

Answer (score 2):

By the Taylor series expansion, as $n \to \infty$, one has
$$
\begin{align}
 \frac{1}{2^n}\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^{n^2}&= \frac{1}{2^n}e^{\large n^2\ln\left(1+\frac{1}{n} \right)}
\\\\&=\frac{1}{2^n}e^{n+O\large \left(\frac{1}{n}\right)}
\\\\&\sim\frac{e^n}{2^n}
\\\\& \to \infty \quad \left( \frac{e}{2}>1\right)
\end{align}
$$ then the given series is *divergent*.